# Colombian studing in Germany, wants to Apply for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, germany, applications, colombian-citizens

I am a little bit confused.

I live and study in Germany and I am applying for a UK Tourist visa with my own resources (Part-time Job (450 Euro/Month) and a blocked account). This blocked account is a MUST for foreign Students in Germany.

Do you think I have good chances to get a visa with my part time job?

I’m planning to stay one week. I’m getting also a letter from my employee and I have a letter from my bank, where it explains the money in the Blocked account (German-Visa).

I am a Colombian citizen.

Comment: What type of visa are you applying for?

Comment: As I understand it, German blocked accounts demonstrate that you have the means to support yourself _in Germany_ during your studies. See: https://www.studying-in-germany.org/germany-blocked-account-foreign-students/ That you're providing evidence of this account to UKVI suggests you believe this same account may also be used to demonstrate you have the means to support yourself _during a trip to the UK_. I'm not sure this is a correct assumption.

Comment: Im applying for a Tourism visa f